# matlab morphological closing with imdilate and imerode

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

In the the matlab documentation there is this sentence about closing an image  with imclose:

> The morphological close operation is a dilation followed by an
> erosion, using the same structuring element for both operations

I tried it out but the result is not the same. Can sombody tell me how I can close an image only with imdilate and imerode?

```
I = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0;
    0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0;
    0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0;
    0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0;
    0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
Q = [0 1 0; 0 1 0; 0 1 1];
Q_n = [1 1 0; 0 1 0; 0 1 0];
J = imclose(I,Q)
D = imdilate(I,Q);
S = imerode(D,Q)
```

Closed result:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

dilate and then erode:

```
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     0     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html#mw_1b2f512c-da87-4510-8473-7d62f4035595), `imclose` pads the image. That could be causing the difference.

Comment: so dilate and erode with the same strel will then be correct?

Comment: I did a quick test and that seemed to be the case, but why not try it out yourself? `padarray(I, [x, x], 'both')` where `x` is half the size of the strel, `imdilate`, `imerode` and then trim off the padding.